# Does linux perform a pumount on shutdown?

Tags: linux, sync, umount

I'm using raspbian debian wheezy. I automatically mount USB drives using usbmount. I mount FAT usb drives with the flush option. Now I was wondering. When I shutdown my pi, does it perform the umount command on all the drives? And does it also perform a sync before unmounting to write the buffers to the usb dirve?

I'm asking this because I couldn't find it and I really don't want to loose any data.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, linux has always done an umount on all mounted drives during shutdown. You might even see that it re-mounts some filesystems as read-only to finish the shutdown. Syncing is inherent to umount.

Comment: Okay thank you, but what is the difference between pumount and umount, I thought the pumount does a sync before unmmounting and the umount doesn't.

Comment: I googled it and seems like pumount is just umount for non-superusers.